# Placing Image (Logo) over frametitle in Beamer (Metropolis Template Theme), it appears underneath

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, logos, beamer-metropolis

I am using the Metropolis theme, when I attempt to use logo{} or tikz or even manually place the image, it appears underneath the "banner" that contains frame titles.

I cannot figure out how to bring the image to front (overlay it) on top of the frame title.

M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{frame title}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal working example.

Comment: I woud like to but can't figure out what you might want, since its a large theme.

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal compilable example that illustrates the problem. I do not see why the size of the theme prevents you doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444958/36296 you could redefine the frametitle like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=\moloch@frametitle@padding,%
      rightskip=\moloch@frametitle@padding,%
    ]{frametitle}%
  \moloch@frametitlestrut@start%
  \insertframetitle%
  \nolinebreak%
  \moloch@frametitlestrut@end%
  \hfill
  \raisebox{-0.6ex}{\includegraphics[height=3ex,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame title}
 \begin{block}{Some itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item \alert{Item 1}
   \item Item 2
  \end{itemize}
 \end{block}
 \begin{block}{Some maths}
 \[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2)\]
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @samcarter, I've found your answer useful. Just one more question: How could I even control the horizontal position of the logo in the header? I mean, `\raisebox` allows to control the vertical position, so which command should I use to achieve horizontal control?