# Add elements on the title page beamer template

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

[image]I am using the `Metropolis Beamer Template` https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/metropolis-beamer-theme/qzyvdhrntfmr.

How can I put some other words, like supervisor and co-supervisor, in the right side of the title page?

I tried editing the `beamerinnerthememetropolis.sty` file, but I am not completely understanding how that code works.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444958/31034

Comment: @ferahfeza I'm sorry but that isn't helping me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to adjust vertical space, font size, etc., but you can start from this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
    \vfill%
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \vspace*{2em}
    {\tiny Super Visor: Super Visor's name%
    \par}
    \vspace*{1em}
    {\tiny Co supervisor: Co supervisor's name%
    \par}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\title{Metropolis}
\subtitle{A modern beamer theme}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Center for modern beamer themes}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to move those elements a little bit on the right: why this code doesn't align them properly? \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
   \vspace*{2em}
   {\hfil\small Super Visor:%
    \par}   
   {\hfil\small Co supervisor: %
    \par}
  \end{minipage}
  \vfill
  \vspace*{1mm}
 \end{minipage}

Comment: @ScTALE  to move them to the right, change minipages width to your taste. About vertical alignment, I don't know how to do it better. You'll have to play with vertical distances to adjust. Unless you wait for a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer in my comment can help us. Changing `\includegraphics` with `minipage` environment in that answer, following code is extracted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[numbering=none,block=fill]{metropolis}

%\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\normalfont\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge,series=\normalfont\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\normalsize,series=\normalfont\bfseries}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black!2, bg=mDarkTeal}
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{My footline}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@frametitle@padding}{0.7ex}% <- default 2.2 ex

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth, sep=0.7ex]{footline}% <- default 3ex
        \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
        \usebeamertemplate*{frame footer}
        \hfill%
        \usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=\metropolis@frametitle@padding,%
      rightskip=\metropolis@frametitle@padding,%
    ]{frametitle}%
  \metropolis@frametitlestrut@start%
  \insertframetitle%
  \nolinebreak%
  \metropolis@frametitlestrut@end%
  \hfill
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
 \small Prof.Dr. Nikola Tesla
  \small Prof.Dr. John Doe
  \end{minipage}

  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame title}
 \begin{block}{Some itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item \alert{Item 1}
   \item Item 2
  \end{itemize}
 \end{block}
 \begin{block}{Some maths}
 \[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2)\]
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question and I added an image to explain better  what I would like to have